# How to make Pandas Excel writer append to an existing sheet in a workbook instead of creating a new worksheet?

Tags: pandas, openpyxl, pandas.excelwriter

I have a excel workbook with two sheets ('variable','fixed'). In parallel, I have a data frame (pandas) with some data. I want to append the data in the data frame to the sheet ('variable') below the existing data in that sheet. But, the following code creates a new sheet called 'variable1' and dumps the data instead of appending to sheet 'variable'.

```
path = "data.xlsx"
book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
writer.book = book
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="variable",startrow=9,
index=False,header=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

I have tried the above code. df3 is my pandas dataframe. I want my data to be pasted from row 9 as the existing data is until row 8 in sheet 'variable'. The code creates a new sheet ('variable1') and dumps data from row 9. I want it to paste the info in sheet ('variable') and not create a new one. 
Can someone help me understand this dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append an excel document use:

```
# open the workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file_name.xlsx')
# assign a var to worksheet
ws = wb['sheet_name']
```

Then you can do things like:

```
# write to cell 
wb['sheet_name'].cell(row=4, column=1).value = string_to_enter_to_cell

# format cells
for row in ws['A4:L4']:
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = None
            cell.border = no_border
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Finally, I ended up storing the data in two different data frames and concatenating them and putting them in a new excel sheet.@55thSwiss

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you made some progress :)